# Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.°°°°°°° This ocurring when running bundle install --without development test

Tags: ruby, redmine, rmagick

i have this problem when im running the comand:
bundle install --without development test

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> current directory:
>      C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0/ext/RMagick
>      C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20180131-9264-1gsyu6v.rb extconf.rb
>      *** extconf.rb failed ***
>      Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>      libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
>      need configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>          --with-opt-dir
>          --without-opt-dir
>          --with-opt-include
>          --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>          --with-opt-lib
>          --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>          --with-make-prog
>          --without-make-prog
>          --srcdir=.
>          --curdir
>          --ruby=C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>      extconf.rb:141:in ``': No such file or directory - identify -version
>      (Errno::ENOENT)
>          from extconf.rb:141:in `configure_compile_options'
>          from extconf.rb:16:in`initialize'
>          from extconf.rb:548:in `new'
>          from extconf.rb:548:in`'>
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>      C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rmagick-2.16.0 for inspection.
>      Results logged to
>      C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.5.0/rmagick-> 2.16.0/gem_make.out
>
> An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.16.0), and Bundler cannot
>      continue.
>      Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.16.0'` succeeds before bundling.
>
> In Gemfile:
>        rmagick

im doing this to install redmine, and i have all dependencies of ruby updated.

Comment: sorry if its something basic, it my firs time installing this, i am in WINDOWS

Comment: I think ImageMagick is missing from your computer, please follow those step [install imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/advanced-windows-installation.php)